# Unable to set VisualState via DataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, visualstatemanager

I am trying to use visual states to animate some controls in my window. I designed the states in blend and they preview fine in the blend designer. I then tried to trigger these states using a `DataTrigger` with `GoToStateAction`. Unfortunately I cant get the states to trigger this way.

I also tried using an `i:EventTrigger` on `FrameworkElement.Loaded` instead of `ei:DataTrigger` but this does not trigger `ei:GoToStateAction` either

I am able to verify the States work by manually triggering `VisualStateManager` in the code behind. Any thoughts on why the `VisualStates` are not being triggered using `ei:GoToStateAction`?

I have references to `System.Windows.Interactivity` and `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions`, both v 4.5

```
<Window ...
                   xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
                   xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModels:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid MinHeight="700"
          ClipToBounds="True"
          Name="MyGrid">

        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Items">
                <VisualState x:Name="MenuState" .../>
                <VisualState x:Name="JobState" .../>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowingJob}" Value="True">
                <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="JobState"
                                    TargetName="MyGrid"/>
            </ei:DataTrigger>
            <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowingJob}" Value="False">
                <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="MenuState"
                                    TargetName="MyGrid"/>
            </ei:DataTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="260"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid>            
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel x:Name="MenuItems"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <TranslateTransform X="-260"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel x:Name="JobItems" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <TranslateTransform X="-260"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>

        <ContentControl />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```